# Why can't I add with method?`

Tags: c#, entity-framework

My unit class:

```
[Column("FldKeyId")]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
[Required]
[Key]
public int MyKeyId { get; set; }

[Column("FldCode")]
[Required]
[Index(IsUnique = true)]
public int MyCode
{
        get { return _Code; }
        set { _Code = value; }
}

[Column ("FldName")]
[Required]
public string MyName { get; set; }

[Column("FldDescription")]
[Required]
public string MyDescription { get; set; }

[Column("FldModifiedUserId")]
[Required]
public int ModifiedUserId { get; set; }

[Column("FldModificationDate")]
[Required]
public DateTime ModificationDate { get; set; }

[Column("FldDeleteFlag")]
[Required]
public int DeleteFlag { get; set; }

public Company Company { get; set; }
```

I have a method for `Add` :

```
public static void AddUnit(int Code,string Name,string Description,int ModifiedUserId,DateTime ModificationDate,Company CompanyId)
{
    ContexManager contex = new ContexManager();
    Unit Row = new Unit()
        {
            MyCode = Code,
            MyName = Name,
            MyDescription = Description,
            ModifiedUserId = ModifiedUserId,
            ModificationDate = ModificationDate,
            Company=CompanyId,
            DeleteFlag = 0
        };

    contex.units.Add(Row);
    contex.SaveChanges();
}
```

For get companyId I have another method:

```
public static Company GetCompany(int KeyId)
{
    ContexManager contex=new ContexManager();
    Company Row = new Company();
    Row = contex.Companies.Where(c => c.MyKeyId == KeyId).Single();

    return Row;
}
```

now for used this :

```
Unit.AddUnit(10, "ab", "bch", 2, DateTime.Now, Company.GetCompany(6));
```

I have a record that companyId is 6 but the problem is when I add `Unit` a `Company` added too...

I use Entity Framework.

Now what do I have to do?

Comment: does this class has any validation rules?

Comment: Did you check inner exception? you can expand inner exception to view more errors and tell us what is in inner exception message.

Comment: check inner exception , it might for not saved changes in DbContext

Comment: @ShiranDror see the Class i've update the Code

Comment: @HamedJavaheri that's inner exeption {"An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details."}

Comment: @SaeidDoroudi that's inner exeption {"An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details."}

Comment: ok,expand inner exception again for more information.

Comment: @HamedJavaheri {"Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.TblCompany' with unique index 'IX_FldCode'. The duplicate key value is (4).\r\nThe statement has been terminated."}

Comment: show how _Code is set

Comment: ok,Because you have not using same DbContext to add Unit.you must using same DbContext.

Comment: @ShiranDror waht's you mean?

Comment: @HamedJavaheri i just have a one DbContext fot both of classes my problem was IsUniqe company's myCode Now new Problem is: when unit added a cpmpany too added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to mark company state to unchanged, try this:

```
ContexManager contex = new ContexManager();
// change Company CompanyId parameter to objCompany as it is not Id
context.Entry(objCompany).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
Unit Row = new Unit()
    {
        MyCode = Code,
        MyName = Name,
        MyDescription = Description,
        ModifiedUserId = ModifiedUserId,
        ModificationDate = ModificationDate,
        Company=objCompany,
        DeleteFlag = 0
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

I think help you:

```
using (ContexManager contex = new ContexManager())
            {
     var company = contex.Companies.Where(c => c.MyKeyId == companyId).Single();
        Row = contex.Companies.Where(c => c.MyKeyId == KeyId).Single();
                Unit Row = new Unit()
                {
                    MyCode = Code,
                    MyName = Name,
                    MyDescription = Description,
                    ModifiedUserId = ModifiedUserId,
                    ModificationDate = ModificationDate,
                    Company = company,
                    DeleteFlag = 0
                };
                contex.units.Add(Row);
                contex.SaveChanges();
            }
```

Comment: Company Is a Company object i cant check == with int

Comment: I didn't say check Company Object == int. I just move GetCompany block code in AddUnit as same DbContext.

Comment: yes now i undrestand your mean, but 2 line above unit row have errors

Comment: i've Update the main question a new problem

Comment: no errors,problem is when i add Unit, Unit added but a company with propertice of company with keyId=6 added too